# Resolve a JIRA ISSUE using REST API in java

Tags: jira-rest-api

A backend API generates JIRA-ISSUE ID.

How do I *close* the jira ticket through REST API calls?

Can somebody help me as to how to proceed with this?

What are the requirements and steps to follow?

Comment: Did you do anything in terms of code or you are just researching?

Comment: Still researching

Answer (score 0):

first list the next transition id

```
https://yourServer/rest/api/3/issue/FOO-123/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

and then use your transition id (212) to update

```
curl -u $JIRA_TOKEN -X POST --data '{ "transition": {"id": "212"} }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://yourServer/rest/api/3/issue/FOO-123/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```